# How do I handle methods taking in a variable amount of inputs?

Tags: python

So basically say I have a class inheriting from a parent.

```
class old_people:
    def get_age(self, vision, wrinkles, grey_hair):
        pass
class female(old_people):
```

say I have mary = female() and I already have her vision. how would i do:
        mary.get_age(wrinkles, grey_hair) without changing the placements of the variables?

Comment: You can pass input in a list and traverse the list and return list with values from the function

Comment: i can't really do that. is there another way?

Comment: What prevents you from declaring `def get_age(self, wrinkles, grey_hair)` in class `female` ? or keep `vision` and simply ignoring it in this class ?

Comment: because then i would have to define that in male as well, so i thought that is bad practice.

Comment: Otherwise you can use default parameters, but in that case as well you will have to change the parameters while calling and returning

Comment: If you only pass two parameters how is `get_age` supposed to know which ones you mean? The first two? The last two? The first and the last?

Comment: I think this might be a good use case for `**kargs`

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure I understand what you mean. But perhaps you want `functools.partialmethod`? With this you can bind fixed values to the first parameters of a method.

```
from functools import partialmethod

class old_people:
    def get_age(self, vision, wrinkles, grey_hair):
        return 100*vision + 10*wrinkles + grey_hair

class female(old_people):
    get_age = partialmethod(old_people.get_age, 2)

mary = female()
mary.get_age(1,4)
# 214
```